# zf2 root url static and dynamic

Tags: frameworks, zend-framework2, url-routing

I currently am using static routes, but I was wondering if you can have static and dynamic routes together. So I am using this:

```
    'contact' => array(
        'type' => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/contact',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                'action'     => 'contact',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

and I would like to use something like this alongside that

```
    'contact' => array(
        'type' => 'segment',
        'options' => array(
            'route'    => '/:curated_url',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                'action'     => 'curated',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

The dynamic route will accept everything though and hijack the static routes. So then I was looking at using the actions routing, but that `curated_url` could be anything.

Is there any way to possibly use the dynamic one and have defaults where if it is not in there then it will look in the database to see if it is in there?

********** EDIT **********

So here is what I spun up for the time being and it works but I know there is a better way, I just don't know that better way.

router.config.php

```
'curated-url' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:url',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'action'     => 'custom',
        ),
    ),
),
```

IndexController.php

```
/*
 * Special kind of special
 */
public function customAction()
{
    $params = array();
    $type = $this->params('url');

    if ('contact' == $type) {
        $params = $this->contactAction($this->getRequest());
    } else if ('discover' == $type) {
        $params = $this->discoverAction();
    } else if ('how-it-works' == $type) {
        $params = $this->howItWorksAction();
    } else if ('privacy-policy' == $type) {
        $params = $this->privacyPolicyAction();
    } else if ('questions' == $type) {
        $params = $this->questionsAction();
    } else if ('terms-of-use' == $type) {
        $params = $this->termsOfUseAction();
    } else if ('volunteer' == $type) {
        $params = $this->volunteerAction();
    } else {
        $params = $this->curatedAction($type);
        $type = 'curated';
    }

    $view = new ViewModel($params);
    $view->setTemplate('application/index/' . $type);

    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you meant, but I believe you need to specify the constraints key, let me show you how:

```
'contact' => array(
    'type' => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '/:curated_url',
        'constraints' => array(
            'curated_url' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'action'     => 'curated',
        ),
    ),
),
```

So then if you passsomething like:

https://yoururl.com/aaaAAA1_2

It will point to the curated action.

Comment: So constraints will only restrict what can be matched, I am wanting to have my default routes; `/about-us`, `/contact`, `/privacy-policy`, etc.. But also have my dynamic routes along side, so my user created routes which in this case are going to be group names (ie - `/dev-group`, `/just-another-group` also they will not always have group on the end of them). The dynamically created routes will be in the database whereas my default routes are currently in static files.

Comment: not sure if I understood, but I use to do it passing something like /type/id/free-text-for-seo.html, so for example: /group-name/1/administrator.html, if this is what you need then you can play with constraints, and then on the action you would check if the id is valid

Comment: I posted an update which might explain what I am trying to do

Comment: ok so what you need for that is a route that will go to "curated" with a regex that match every text             'curated_url' => '.*', then create all the static routes, ZF2 will know which one to pick based on the order, so first the static then the regex

Comment: I heard that I could do a hashmap or something along those lines